# how to update subtotal in shoppping cart quantity?

Tags: php, sql

After i added one more quantity to one of my selected product the subtotal not given me a right checkout total once i press update button,its only read the single quantity right while calculating them showing wrong final total.

```
            <table align="center" width="700" bgcolor="white">

                <tr align="center">
                    <th>Remove</th>
                    <th>Product(S)</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>

    <?php 
    $total = 0;

    global $connection; 

    $ip = getIp(); 

    $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

    $run_price = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_price); 

    while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){

        $pro_id = $p_price['p_id']; 

        $pro_price = "select * from Product where Product_ID='$pro_id'";

        $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($connection,$pro_price); 

        while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){

        $product_price = array($pp_price['Price']);

        $product_title = $pp_price['Product_Name'];

        $product_image = $pp_price['Image']; 

        $single_price = $pp_price['Price'];

        $values = array_sum($product_price); 

        $total += $values; 

                ?>

                <tr align="center">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>"/></td>
                    <td style="border:1; color:black;"><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
                    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>" width="60" height="60"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>"/></td>

                    <?php 

                    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

                        $qty = $_POST['qty'];

                        $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

                        $run_qty = mysqli_query($connection, $update_qty); 

                        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

                        $total = $total*$qty;
                    }


                    ?>


                    <td><?php echo "$" . $single_price; ?></td>
                </tr>


            <?php } } ?>






            <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="right"><b>Sub Total:</b></td>
                    <td><?php echo "$" . $total;?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" /></td>
                    <td><button><a href="checkout.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">Checkout</a></button></td>
                </tr>

            </table> 

        </form>
```

I think the problem is here (not sure)

```
<?php 

                        if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

                            $qty = $_POST['qty'];

                            $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

                            $run_qty = mysqli_query($connection, $update_qty); 

                            $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

                            $total = $total*$qty;
                        }


                        ?>
```

Here are the links one for the actual page and the other one for my database

http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1430742773071.png
http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1430742841161.png

Comment: You made mistake in update qry. `where` condition is missed in your `update cart set qty='$qty'`. For which item you are updating cart.? Please check that

Comment: i have changed the query into this $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' WHERE p_id ='$pro_id'"; but still not working. :) so what possible solution should i do

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajax post method to extract them...

use the php code below to extract cart single subtotal:

```
$this->cart->contents()['eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3']['subtotal']
```